# Set expires to max for all images of all servers in nginx

Tags: caching, nginx, browser-cache, server-configuration, expires-header

I have an nginx setup with multiple server blocks. I'd like to know if there's a way to globally set the value of `expires` to `max` for all images, CSS and JS across the server.

I know I can use this:

```
location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
   expires max;
}
```

But then I'd have to add it to every server block, since `location` isn't allowed in `http`.

Is there a way to set `expires` to `max` for specific mime-types or extensions, globally?

Comment: you can add it in a separate config file, and import it in all ur servers

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady that would be the awesome workaround (thanks!) :) I'll use that unless/until a neater syntax is possible. Could you write an example for this workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it first cause I haven't tested this before.

conf file `/etc/nginx/img-cache.conf` for example

```
location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
    expires max;
}
```

server

```
server {
    #bla bla
    include /etc/nginx/img-cache.conf;
    #bla bla
}
```

Comment: does it work if you comment the `expires` line but leave the include ?

Comment: How did you make it work? If I do this my images get broken too, and I think it may be because I need to write a root directive somewhere but I don't see how to write it once for all my websites...

Comment: My webpage started hanging after i did this.

Comment: The page keeps displaying as loading but never loads

Comment: @Rakshith I don't think this could be caused by this, if you want you could post your config in a new question and I'll take a look at it.